# How to import a module in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have two js files: **MyBreakdown.js** and **MyService.js** and I want to import the second one into the first one.

There are in different subfolders of the same directory, like this:

```
server/reports/plan/MyService.js
```

and

```
serer/validation/rules/sections/MyBreakdown.js
```

So what I've tried in MyBreakdown.js file is to import MyService.js in two ways but none of them worked:

1. `const seasonalityService = require('server/reports/plan/myService');`
2. `const seasonalityService = require('../../../../myService');`

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Imports are by filename.

Comment: these are both files created by me, not core modules

Comment: **Imports are by filename**, while the extension can be omitted.

Comment: I didn't import them with the extension as it can be seen in the 2 ways I tried to do it.

Comment: You can even import the module using the absolute path as follow `const seasonalityService = require('path_to_myproject/server/reports/plan/MyService');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module imports in NodeJS are done by *filenames*. For instance:

```
const seasonalityService = require('../../../../reports/plan/MyService');
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are inside - serer/validation/rules/sections/MyBreakdown.js

Use `path.join` to form the right path.

```
var path = require('path');

var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../', '/reports/plan/MyService');

console.log(filepath);

var serviceFile = require(filepath);
```